# Homogeneous second order differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have am not sure how to solve this problem after I have found the solutions of its characteristic equation.

[image]

So what I have is:

$\lambda^2+2x+3=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=-1\pm \sqrt{2}i$

then solution would be: $y =c_1e^{-t}cos(\sqrt{2}t)+c_1e^{-t}sin(\sqrt{2}t)+c_1e^{-t}cos(-\sqrt{2}t)+c_1e^{-t}sin(-\sqrt{2}t)  $

What would be $ \psi(t)$ and $ \phi(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that the differential equation of the Wronskian determinant $W=φψ'-φ'ψ$ is homogeneous of first order, thus easy to solve
\begin{alignat}{1}
W'&=\frac{d}{dt}(φψ'-φ'ψ)&&=φψ''-φ''ψ\\&=φ(-2ψ'-3ψ)-(-2φ'-3φ)ψ&&=-2(φψ'-φ'ψ)
\\&=-2W
\end{alignat}
so that 
$$
W(t)=e^{-2t}W(0)=e^{-2t}(φ(0)ψ'(0)-φ'(0)ψ(0))
$$
and for the given values that is $W(0.4)=39e^{-0.8}=17.52382960...$

Comment: Can you explain the last step a bit more. This is due to the homogeneity of the Wronskian?

Comment: Yes, the Wronskian has the differential equation $W'=-2W$ and this has the solution $W(t)=e^{-2t}W(0)$.

Comment: Ah this is Abel’s theorem. Of course!! Nice answer. Wish I could remove mine now!!